# boto3 vpc_exists waiter returns before VPC exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I got the following error when trying to set a VPC's tags after creating it (once out of a few dozen tries. It works most of the time, but not always):

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidVpcID.NotFound) when calling the CreateTags operation: The vpc ID 'vpc-4240de24' does not exist
```

I checked afterwards, and the VPC vpc-4240de24 did exist, so CreateTags was called too early.

The error occurred in the following method:

```
def create_vpc(self, region, vpc_name):
    """create VPC in region and attach tags (threaded)"""
    ec2_client = aws.ec2_client(region) # Custom method, essentially calls boto3.client('ec2')
    vpc_id = ec2_client.create_vpc(
        CidrBlock="172.31.0.0/16",
        AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock=False
    )["Vpc"]["VpcId"]
    # TODO: Attach tags on VPC creation when (if) it becomes supported
    ec2_client.get_waiter("vpc_exists").wait(VpcIds=[vpc_id])
    ec2_client.create_tags(
        Resources=[vpc_id],
        Tags=[
            {
                "Key": "Namespace",
                "Value": config.NAMESPACE
            },
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": vpc_name
            }
        ]
    )
```

I do not understand how getting that error is even possible. Shouldn't the vpc_exists waiter return only when the VPC exists, and raise the WaiterError exception otherwise? I would set a sleep for 1 second after the waiter, but is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but can you try `vpc_available` waiter? It has a much larger wait timeout and polling interval that `vpc_exists` waiter.

Comment: So you're saying the method looks fine. I'll switch over to vpc_available then. Hopefully it will prevent this problem from resurfacing.

Comment: You should consider cloudformation if you need to do this often.  As long as AWS doesn't give a VPC create token API that let do an async query on the status of the VPC, cloudformation is the only way to do away with the tedious waiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can now tag the VPC on creation

```
response = client.create_vpc(
    CidrBlock='string',
    AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock=True|False,
    Ipv6Pool='string',
    Ipv6CidrBlock='string',
    DryRun=True|False,
    InstanceTenancy='default'|'dedicated'|'host',
    Ipv6CidrBlockNetworkBorderGroup='string',
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'vpc',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
)
```